# Which expression has priority in `v[--i] = 100;`? the subscripting or the unary expression

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

This is more of a fundamental question rather than a useful one but here it goes.

According to the C++ standard, postfix expressions (e.g., `v[i]`), have priority over unary expressions (e.g., `--i`). Therefore, I was wondering what is the actual sequence of steps that a program follows to implement this statement `v[--i] = 100;`.

```
std::vector<int> v = {0, 200};
int i = 1;
v[--i] = 100; // {100, 200}
```

Given the aforementioned priorities, does the program first access the element 200 of the vector, and only then the decrement happens, pointing to 0 before changing it to 100?

Comment: You can't evaluate `v[x]` until you evaluate `x` regardless of operator priority.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator []` has higher precedence than `operator --`, but that doesn't matter here because `operator[]` needs to evaluate the parameter which is `--i` which means `--i` is resolved and then it's value is passed along to `operator[]`

Operator precedence is not the same as the order of operations .  Operator precedence only determines which operators are applied to which expressions.